# SSRS Hiding Images with expression doesn't work in header

Tags: image, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm new to SSRS and I already found my first big problem.
I need to make a page with all personal information from people.
But I need to add images in the header.
If the person doesn't have a picture of himself I take an avatar image.
So I hide the picture picturebox en show the avatar picturebox.

[Design of the Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hfd3Q.jpg)

[Result when no profile picture found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSGAV.jpg)

But when I preview the SSRS when the pboxes in the header I get an error :

> The Hidden expression for the image 'Picture' contains an error : Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken:b77a5c561934e089' failed.

And if i move the images out of the header it works...

So this is the code I use to hide the images.

```
=IIf((First(Fields!found.Value, "DataSet4") = "TRUE"), True, False)
=IIf((First(Fields!found.Value, "DataSet4") = "FALSE"), True, False)
```

> found contains only "TRUE" or "FALSE"

Or isn't it  possible to hide items in the header of the page?

Comment: You're not putting both lines of code in one expression are you? You only need one or the other.

Comment: Yea i put one line in 1 picturebox.
Its just the code for the 2 pictureboxes together.
Sorry for the confusion